# Is it possible to play an audio in apple watch simulator? - Xcode 10.1

Tags: swift, watchkit, avaudioplayer, apple-watch, watchos

I am trying to play an audio in apple watch simulator but it keeps giving this error.

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (**OSStatus** error 2003334207.)

Is it possible to play an audio with simulator?
Audio url is fine.
Here is my code.

```
self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url as URL)
player?.prepareToPlay()
player?.volume = 10.0
player?.play()
```

Comment: That error is `kAudioFileUnspecifiedError` which is vague. What kind of format audio data is that? Is it a file url or a remote url?

Comment: it is an mp3 format and it is a remote url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to play an audio with remote URL in apple watch.
You need download it first and then play it.
Now it's working fine and I can play the audio in simulator as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
let asset  = AVURLAsset(url: url!, options: nil)
let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
self.player.play()
self.player.volume = 10.0
```

Comment: You can play audio with the code.
It works well for mp3 file as well as m3u8 files.

Comment: does this work with a remote URL? Your answer should be updated to include some explanation about why it works and the code in the question doesn't

Comment: Yes, it works.
Recent watchOS allows AVPlayer to play the audio files as well.